# DataSets vs DataClasses as return type from WCF services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I need to path information from BL layer to the presentation layer via WCF services .

I thought to do it via DataSets but I saw that people tell that it's a bad practice and it's recommended to use dataclasses.

Can someone  explain the difference and the advantages .

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataSet is an old-school, outdated like-an-OR/M solution which worked fine for a long time in *drag&drop developments*.

Once you want to expose some logic over a service using WCF or any other framework, you need to take in account that these should transport no useless data and just what client needs to consume, and a client could be an *user interface* or just another service or backend engine.

In services like WCF the best approach is *DTO* (*data-transfer objects*, also known as *value objects*), which are a light-weight versions of business objects, absolutely unlinked from any layer (it doesn't depend on business, UI, data...) which can be easly serialized into XML or JSON and deserialized in any platform, not only in strongly-typed environments, but also interpreted, dinamically-typed ones, like JavaScript, PHP, Python or Ruby (or many others).

Think about DTO as a class which has the exact number of properties that some consumer needs to work with your service layer.

*Practical example:* You've a *Person* class having a Name, SecondName and Age. In your user interface, you need to query some service for a list of *Person* and there you need to show *SecondName* only. In this case, you're going to design a class having a single property *SecondName* and you'll avoid giving a full *Person* to the user interface through your service layer, because it's cheaper and, obviously, optimal.

If this service layer returns *PersonDto* objects, a JSON-serialized list of 3 persons would be `[{ "SecondName": "Blah" }, { "SecondName": "Bleh" }, { "SecondName": "Blih" }]`. I don't think a *DataSet* would be that lighty serialization.

Check these articles about *DTO*:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx

Comment: I nearly agree - only that data retrieval services should use ODATA and with ODATA the user can filter out properties, so a separate "surname only" dto is unnecessary. .NET natively support OData for quite some time now.

Comment: @TomTom I dind't know about this standard. Thank for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Try that - a WCF service should be platform independant, and a DataSet is not. You do not transfer defined documents with DataSets but the internal representation of a .NET specific object.

Try that - a DataSet has a lot of crappy functionality that needs representation in the XML form (change information etc.) but that is totally irrelevant in a properly designed API (which a web servie is).

Try that - no project I have known in the last 10 years from any person I do not consider a junior had a DataSet anywhere, WCF or not. Most people with knowledge went over to OR mappers many many years ago.

Comment: I'll say I'm agreed with your first 2 points, but last one isn't a solid argument, "it or it's not because **everyone** do **X**". Say technology advances and approaches changes like anything in the world :D DataSet had its momentum in .NET 1.x-2.0, then, .NET and OR/M frameworks got maturity and DataSet became an obsolete solution and a complete overkill. It's like _arrays_, which are necessary, but nowadays .NET solutions relies more on collections because of their interesting features :D

Comment: I used an OR mapper 1 years ago way before .NET. I uwrote one for .NET 1.0. Sorry - ignorance by 70% of the decvelopers in the .NET world is a fallacy. When .nET 1.0 came out, ORM were a mature technology.

Comment: You've misunderstood my words. OR/M was a mature approach since Hibernate and others were in the ground in Java in others. And, in my case, I developed an attribute-based OR/M mapper like Fluent NHib with some of its features for .NET 1.x too, because non of existing OR/M frameworks for .NET were absolutely mature, stable and they didn't have a great community like now.

Comment: In the first .NET moments, WinForms and ASP.NET controls were very DataSet-friendly while working with pure object collections was more a "custom task". That's all.

Comment: Yes. Like often - proper programming is a task, not some drag and drop.

Comment: That's why I've never developed an application using DataSet! I hate drag&drop developments. Developing software isn't a thing you'd like to avoid, if you love what you do, and you want to be a good professional, I'm absolutely agreed too, programming is a task, or a process defined by an actual scientist method :)

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer , can you please refer me to some working example how people doing this .

Comment: @NightWalker Check my answer, I gave you some links. DTO is a design pattern, meaning that's a common solution for solving an scenario like yours.

Answer (score 2):

I blogged about this [here](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,0a7cd196-c36b-4afa-ab02-5e4e6829c42d.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

With untyped datasets, you can't really shape the data you are passing to clients, including your presentation layer. For internal apis this is less of an issue, but if you're planning on expanding your api usage, you should consider the benefits if using statically typed models rather that a broad data container. This counts for both inputs and outputs. With a typed model, you can better define the intended shape of your data, its behaviour and with shared contracts you can take advantage of a shared validation model.