# Why can't I add a dataset to my WCF Web Service project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services

I'm new to WCF Web Services and I'm making my first one. I need to access my SQL database in the service. Typically, I add a dataset to my projects and drag my tables from server explorer to the dataset and work from there.  That doesn't seem to be available in the WCF Web Service project. Is there a way to do that? If not, how do I access my sql database tables?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9015682/74757).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I never figured out how to add a dataset through the add new item in the project, but I was able to copy a dataset from another project and use it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It's a very simple and straight forward library and it's only one file! In fact Stack Overflow uses Dapper. Further, it's extremely fast. Let's assume you have a table named `Customer` and it looked like this:

```
Id int
Name varchar(255)
```

Well, with Dapper you would simply create a POCO class that looked like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then since Dapper just extends the `IDbConnection` interface, when you create a `SqlConnection` and add the `using` statement at the top of the class you want to query the data in, the Dapper methods show up on that connection object.

The link has very good documentation on how to use the library.

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't use the datasets I've always used?

Comment: No, you can still add a typed `DataSet` to your project, use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill it, and work with that set as usual. But you're building web services and so you won't see any real benefits of the `DataSet` like data binding - it's just heavy. You're getting a request and then returning data, thus making a very light and fast implementation the right approach. Besides, you can't **easily** return the `DataSet` or `DataTable` as a result from a web service call because it must be serialized by **hand** and that's very cumbersome - trust me. However, the POCO can.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Why then when I try to add a new item to the project, dataset is not one of the options? My only preference for the dataset is my familarity with them. When I go back to the code in a month, I know I will understand it. Idon't have to return a dataset, just need to work with it internally in the service. Thanks again.